# PHP - When a checkbox gets checked send a request to run a query on the database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I've been working on this code for awhile now and I've done a lot of debugging but can't figure this out. What I want to do is: if a checkbox is checked send a request to run a query on the mySQL database FROM items WHERE .class(of the checkbox) '<' this.value(of the checkbox again) then get the filtered results and then use my javascript to format it:

index.php:

```
<form>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="calories "name="calories" value="300">Less  than 300</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="calories" name="calories" value="500">Less than  500</label><br>    
</form>

<script>
$("input.calories:checkbox").on("change",function(){

  if(this.checked){               

    var column = $(this).attr('class'); //The class determines which column of the table is called    
    var value = $(this).attr('value'); //Takes the numeric value from the selected box
    console.log(column); 
    //$.post('showItems.php', {type: column});
    //$.post('showItems.php', {value: value});

   //Can we call the php code above to run a query using variables column and value? 
   //make a php function above and call it

    // function below will run showItemss.php?c=column?v=value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "showItems.php" ,
            data: { c: column,
                    v: value},
            error: function(){console.log("error")},
            success: function(data) { 
              console.log("success");
            console.log(test);
            console.log(filteredList);
</script>
```

Here is the PHP file showItems.php I'm calling (the relevant part):

```
    //This array holds items from database.
$itemList = array();

//Connect and Select    
$con = makeConnection($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

  //Get the value and type from the javascript below
  //If the type is null display the whole table
  $c = $_POST['c'];
  //echo $c;

  //$v = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$v);
  //$type = $_POST['value'];
  if($c==null){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items";
  }
  else{
  $v = $_POST['v'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE ".$c."< ".$v."";  
  }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//Collect data from all items
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tempItem = new Item($row['itemID'], $row['itemName'],  $row['price'], $row['description'], $row['calories'], $row['protein'], $row['choles'], $row['sodi'], $row['picLink']);

        $itemList[] = $tempItem;
    }
  echo json_encode($query);
?>

  <script>
    var test = <?php echo json_encode($query); ?>;
    var filteredList = <?php echo json_encode($itemList); ?>;
  </script>
```

So I want this code to be run every time I click a checkbox in my Index.php file so I can get the updated filtered items, $itemList, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Something I've done to test this is store my php values as javascript variables, Include showItems.php then console.log the variables from ShowItems.php in Index.php, and the query isn't being updated upon click which makes sense I guess. In the AJAX success function 'data' contains the entire HTML source with an updated query, but I can't figure out how use only the specific code I need in the success function. Any ideas at all would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

- Go from `on("change",...)` to `on("click",...)`
- Also try using instead of `this.checked`, `$(this).prop("checked")` which will return you true or false depending on wether the checkbox is checked or not.
- You might want to change either  your selector or your checkbox classes because both are the same, and can give you undesired functionality in order to get your values when you click on a checkbox, since the selector finds you both checkboxes.

Hope this ideas can get you closer where you want to be.
Cheers

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken shouldn't my selector be the name of my checkbox class? Or am I confused with something else? And no it didn't help me, I've been able to confirm that the onclick/onchange functions do in fact work I believe it's either my AJAX code or PHP code that needs to be fixed

Comment: Yes, but that way jQuery will find both checkboxes since they have the same class and will not give you the result you want, try doing a console.log on your `$(this).attr('value')` and `...('class')` variables and you'll see what I mean, try to debug your PHP by var_dumping your $_POST variable in your network tab of your browser's developer tools, and see if they are being passed correctly in to your $_POST.